# admob display with smartface 4.4

Tags: smartface.io

If you try to include `admob ios xcode` gives following error and fails for `admob` plugin. How to solve the problem? Or for the new version `admob` plugin has been cancelled?

```
"SpEventGroup::FireEvent(TEventID, int, char*, SpBrParcelable*)", referenced from:
      -[SpBrAdViewDelegate adViewDidReceiveAd:] in libAdmobEnabled.a(SpBrAdViewDelegate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Is there any body else who can display admob for ios? As i see the updated version of `"Smartface in Action"` also don't show `admob`.

Comment: AdMob is supported but there is an issue about this plugin right now. It will be fixed with the upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you Merve! Looking for new release before buying individual license to be fixed basic functionalities like file operations, admob..